# Rails migration for a model that references two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails app has two models: **User** and **Puzzle**. I'm adding a **Solve** model which represents the solving of **one specific puzzle** by a user. The solve captures things like how quickly the user solved the puzzle. Ultimately, I only want to record the *first time* a user solves a specific puzzle, but for now I'm just trying to make sure I get the relationships between the models right.

Here's my migration for the new Solves table:

```
class CreateSolves < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :solves do |t|
      t.integer :time
      t.integer :attempts
      t.references :user
      t.references :puzzle

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

... and here is the Solve model:

```
class Solve < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :puzzles, through: :user
end
```

Here is the create method in solves_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @solve = Solve.new(solve_params)
    @solve.user = current_user
    @solve.puzzle = Puzzle.find(params["puzzle"]) # <----- THIS LINE

    respond_to do |format|
      if @solve.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @solve.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When the user completes the puzzle, I send an ajax request to log their time, which includes the puzzle ID. Everything is working so far *except* the line labeled THIS LINE. When I added that, I get the error:

**undefined method `puzzle=' for #Solve:0x00007fd6ed434830 Did you mean? puzzles= puzzles**

I think that maybe I haven't set-up the correct relationship between the puzzle, user, and solve appropriately for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :solves
  has_many :puzzles, through: :solves 
end

class Solve < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :puzzle
end

class Puzzle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :solves
  has_many :users, through: :solves 
end
```

However Solve is a very awkward model name as it not actually a noun in English. Since models are things they should be nouns and not not verbs. `Solution` is a noun.

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the has_many and belongs_to statements in the other models. And you're right, `Solve` is not really an English noun - in fact, Rails had some trouble with the default inflection (singular/plural) and I had to modify the inflections configuration. I'll probably switch back to `Solution`.